# two outer angle are not equal

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

i want to  know one thing are  two outer angle of triangle different from each other?let us consider following problem

n the figure above, $AD = AC = CB.$ 
If the value of $y$ is $28$, what is the value of $x$?

[image]

i have calculated  angles and  got that angle $ACD=ADC=56$,so  angle $x$ should equal  to angles  $112$,but maybe i missed something and not include  angle $DAC$ and  angle  $BAC$ in calculation,just  suppose that $x$ ax external angle  is equal to angle  $ADC$+$ACD$,so which one is correct?please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $AC=CB$, $CAB=CBA=y$. Now, $x+CAD+CAB=180$ and $CAD+ADC+ACD=180$, so $CAD=180-112=68$ and $x=180-CAD-CAB=180-68-28=84$.  
  
But even more is true: since the triangle $ACD$ is isosceles, the height to the chord $CD$ through $A$ must halve the angle $CAD= 2 \alpha$. So suppose $x=y$, then we still have $x+y+2\alpha =180$, but also $x+ \alpha = y+\alpha$ and hence $x+ \alpha =90$, which would imply that $AB$ and $CD$ are parallel, which is absurd.

Comment: when can i use  rule   what i have mentioned?

Comment: please see this link http://regentsprep.org/Regents/math/geometry/GP5/LExtAng.htm

Comment: The theorem applies to this situation as well, but $x$ is not an "exterior angle" (as used in the article) of the triangle $ACD$. It is however an exterior angle of the triangle $ABD$, so the theorem would give $x=y+ADC=3y= \frac 32ADC$

Comment: aa it should be continue of any sides right,thanks in advance